# Unable to compare two strings in IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, xml, logic

okay, so I've been trying to build the server-side for a web app that needs to get information from 2 XML files and compare them, one element at a time. For some reason my code will do everything except compare the 2 nodes.

The code:

```
function getCoursesByRole($role){
    s("role is ". $role);
    $xml = getxml(); # get the XML file
    $roles = getRoles();#load the roles file
    $modules = array();
    foreach($roles->children() as $project){
    s($project->name);
        if($project->name == $role){
            s("found:". $role);
            $courses = $project->courses->children();
            #echo "courses   ". $courses;
            foreach($courses as $theCourse){
                foreach($xml->children() as $course){
                    s("looking for $theCourse.... found ".$course->name);
                    if($theCourse == $course->name){
                        s("found $theCourse");
                        array_push($modules, array('name' => $course->name));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #echo array_values($modules);
    return $modules;
}
```

From the output I think the problem is a logic issue.

```
role is core
core
found:core
looking for Fire Safety.... found Administration of Medication
looking for Fire Safety.... found An Introduction to GIRFEC
looking for Fire Safety.... found Equality and Diversity
looking for Fire Safety.... found Fire Safety
looking for Fire Safety.... found Food Safety
looking for Fire Safety.... found Infection Control
looking for Fire Safety.... found Introduction to Health and Safety
looking for Fire Safety.... found Introduction to Safer Handling
looking for Fire Safety.... found Managing Volunteers
looking for Fire Safety.... found QStar
```

I only showed one iteration of `s("looking for $theCourse.... found ".$course->name);` it got quite long

If anybody can see a solution i would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Its always good idea to trim string with trim() function while using as condition if(trim($a) == trim($b)).

Comment: trim removes ( by default ) extra spaces from start / end of string. You can set trim() to remove other chars by adding them as secondary parameters. ie: trim( $string, ';'); etc

Comment: wow, thanks @offshore trimming the strings worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Its always good idea to trim string with trim() function while using as condition if(trim($a) == trim($b)). - offshore

This comment answered my question. after changing this line: `if($theCourse == $course->name){` to this `if(trim($theCourse) == trim($course->name)){` the code worked perfectly.

Comment: please accept your own answer so that your question is marked as successfully answered. let me know if you run into trouble with that.

Comment: i had forgotten to do this; i wasn't allowed to when i initially posted the answer